# Is there some CUDA support in the 'nouveau' driver?

Tags: 20.04, cuda, nouveau

From what I understand the 'nouveau' driver does not support CUDA. I compiled a very simple CUDA program and was very surprised that it did actually run successfully. Is there now some CUDA support in the 'nouveau' driver?

Edit:
What I did was building a simple CUDA program that allocates and initializes a number of arrays of floating point numbers, launches a saxpy kernel and compares the result.
In fact the program ran fine (main returned 0) which had me concluded that also all other part of the program ran fine. Since I'm running the nouveau driver I further concluded that some CUDA support is available. What I did not pay attention to was the fact that the program's result was actually wrong. It looks like the program didn't launch the compute kernel but did everything else. I didn't consider this a possibility.

This is Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 with GFX1070 on Intel based PC.

Comment: How did you verify that the program actually used CUDA resources?

Comment: Dang. Looking closer, the program executed without error but it did the wrong thing. Interesting I would have thought it might crash or complain  without CUDA support.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: I think my question is more related to the silence of the nouveau driver about  CUDA kernel launches. We can close this  question unanswered or we delete it.